# Как обработать исключение java.util.ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java

Есть код: [ссылка на github](https://gist.github.com/cfcbd4585fd44e971888). В ходе выполнения выбрасывается исключение **Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException** [image: Изображение]
Знающие люди подскажите как побороть проблему. Заранее спасибо)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Его не надо обрабатывать. Это исключение значит, что вы в своем коде удаляете элемент напрямую из коллекции во время использования итератора. Т.к. в этом случае появляется неопределенность, откуда итератор должен продолжать и какие последующие элементы должен пройти, выбрасываетс исключение. Для корректного изменения сущности используйте методы итератора, например, `iterator.remove()`.

Comment: А если я использую цикл `for (T item: expr)`?

Answer (score 3):

Например, можно поставить блокировку перед началом модификации ArrayList и снять блокировку после завершения модификации. Используете неконкурентную структуру данных ArrayList. Такая сруктура данных будет корректно работать если поток один.

```
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        synchronized (i) {
            Enemy e = i.next();
            if (e.x >= 1600 || e.x <= -1600) {
                i.remove();
            } else {
                e.move(); // поправить позже
                g.drawImage(e.img, e.x, e.y, null);
            }
        }
    }
```

В этом коде блокировка снимается позже завершения модификации. Можно код переписать так:

```
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        boolean isDrawImage = false;
        synchronized (i) {
            Enemy e = i.next();
            if (e.x >= 1600 || e.x <= -1600) {
                i.remove();
            } else {
                e.move(); // поправить позже
                isDrawImage = true;
            }
        }
        if (isDrawImage)
           g.drawImage(e.img, e.x, e.y, null);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

В дополнение к [ответу](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/454175/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B1%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BB%D1%8E%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-java-util-concurrentmodificationexception#answer-454178) etki привожу код для корректного удаления элемента коллекции внутри цикла итератора:

```
Iterator<String> i = strings.iterator();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    String value = i.next(); // должен быть вызван перед тем, как вызывается i.remove()
    // какой-то код
    i.remove(); // Элемент value был удалён из коллекции strings
}
```